# Fastboot does not see device, but fastbootd does

Tags: adb, rooting, bootloader, tecno

My device: Tecno Camon 19 (cl6n)
I need to unlock bootloader, adb see my phone correctly, fastbootd too. But when I do `adb reboot bootloader` neither the phone nor the PC can see each other. Phone says that after 60 seconds without action, the phone will reboot, and on the PC `fastboot devices` gives an empty line, if you try to use any fastboot command, the text "Waiting for any device" will appear. I installed usb drivers and vc reddists, so i dont know why its not working.

Comment: 1. Try different cables/ports/Laptops 2. If you are using platform tools version 34.xxx roll back to earlier versions. The latest version reportedly doesn't play well with some devices

Comment: You have a Mediatek based device which usually have fastboot mode but with limited use as flashing is done to my knowledge using special software when device is shit down.

Comment: I'm experiencing this symptom with a Pixel 6, adb/fastboot won't show anything in bootloader mode, but fastboot will in fastbootd mode, and adb will when phone booted into OS. Neither works in bootloader mode. I'll comment back if I find an answer

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is with my laptop (and mobile is Red Magic 7), I installed fastboot drivers,
When I boot my device to bootloader using `adb reboot bootloader`, the phone is booting to bootloader, but it is just detected as Android. And when I try to update its driver to Bootloader Interface, Windows says the driver was installed successfully, but there is no change and the device does not get recognised, so `fastboot devices` yields nothing.

But if I do `adb reboot fastboot`, it boots the device to fastbootd mode, and this time the device is being detected as Android Phone: bootloader interface and is detected by platform tools (`fastboot devices`) also.

I still can't figure out why this is happening.